# Sum, product and intersection of ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

An exercise asks me to find the intersection, sum and product of the ideals generated by $x^2+x-2$ and $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

The sum is the smaller ideal containing the union so I think I have to find $d = gcd(x^2+x-2,x^2-1)$ and the sum is the ideal $<d>$

For the intersection I have to find the ideal generated by $lcm(x^2+x-2,x^2-1)$ the greater ideal contained in both ideals.

But I don't have clear what should be the product of both ideals. Is it just the product of both polynoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two principal ideals is indeed the principal ideal generated by the product of both generators.

By definition, the product of ideals $I$ and $J$ in a ring $R$ is the ideal generated by the set $\{xy|x\in I,y\in J\}$. Thus if $I=(f)$ and $J=(g)$, the product is generated by elements of the form $\lambda fg$ for $\lambda\in R$, which obviously already form an ideal, namely $(fg)$.